# Single sign on failing with LinkedIn account to a microsoft website

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, linkedin-api

We are seeing an issue with users unable to access our production and PPE apps via LinkedIn sign in. The redirection is not happening to specified redirect URL once users provides user name and password. The network trace shows login is successful but not going to redirect URL. This has been working last 4 years or so and suddenly started failing in both environments from yesterday.

> Bummer. Something went wrong

[image]

We tried verifying the network trace and a support case is raised to LinkedIn with recording. Finally we are redirected to raise the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that it was caused by using `JSON.stringify` to "overload" the state parameter with other parameters. In my case, I add other parameters in the following way:

```
providerCfg.auth_params.state = JSON.stringify({
  state: providerCfg.auth_params.state,
  redirectPageUrl,
  redirectParams,
  userTypeBit,
  isLogin
})
const authUrl = new URL(providerCfg.auth_url)
Object.entries(providerCfg.auth_params).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  authUrl.searchParams.append(key, encodeURIComponent(val))
})
return buildURL(providerCfg.auth_url, providerCfg.auth_params)
```

When I removed the call to `JSON.stringify` and just passed in a state parameter, the oauth flow worked correctly. Obviously, the other parameters that I passed in were important so I created my own functions to serialize and deserialize the values. The code below works well for anything other than deeply nested objects. You will need to update the `metaDataCfg` based on your own requirements.

```
const META_STRING_DELIMITER = '|'
const serializeBasicObject = (targetObj) => {
  if (!targetObj) {
    return ''
  }
  return Object.entries(targetObj).reduce((objString, [key, val]) => {
    const param = `${key}=${val || ''}`
    if (!objString.length) {
      return param
    }
    return `${objString}${META_STRING_DELIMITER}${param}`
  }, '')
}

const deserializeBasicObject = (targetStr) => {
  if (!targetStr) {
    return ''
  }
  const keyValPairs = targetStr.split(META_STRING_DELIMITER)
  return keyValPairs.reduce((targetObj, keyValPair) => {
    const splitIdx = keyValPair.indexOf('=')
    const key = keyValPair.slice(0, splitIdx)
    targetObj[key] = keyValPair.slice(splitIdx + 1, keyValPair.length)
    return targetObj
  }, {})
}

const metaDataCfg = {
  state: {},
  redirectPageUrl: {},
  redirectParams: {
    serialize: serializeBasicObject,
    deserialize: deserializeBasicObject
  },
  userTypeBit: { deserialize: Number },
  isLogin: { deserialize: dataUtil.getBoolean }
}

const getMetaString = (metaData) => {
  return Object.entries(metaDataCfg).reduce((metaString, [metaDataKey, cfg]) => {
    const val = (cfg.serialize) ? cfg.serialize(metaData[metaDataKey]) : metaData[metaDataKey]
    const param = `${metaDataKey}=${dataUtil.isNil(val) ? '' : val}`
    if (!metaString.length) {
      return param
    }
    return `${metaString}${META_STRING_DELIMITER}${param}`
  }, '')
}

export const getDataFromMetaString = (metaString) => {
  const params = metaString.split(META_STRING_DELIMITER)
  const data = params.reduce((metaData, param) => {
    const splitIdx = param.indexOf('=')
    const key = param.slice(0, splitIdx)
    let val = param.slice(splitIdx + 1, param.length)
    if (dataUtil.isNil(val) || !val.length) {
      return metaData
    }
    const deserializer = metaDataCfg[key].deserialize
    if (deserializer && val) {
      val = deserializer(val)
    }
    metaData[key] = val
    return metaData
  }, {})
  return data
}
```