# Linkedin passport oauth sometimes returns "something went wrong"

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using passport auth with linkedin and node.js and it suddenly started returing . It was working for years, so it's an old code. I haven't changed or updated anything. Checked my logs nothing, checked linkedin logs, nothing. Sometimes it works with some accounts, with others it doesn't.

These are my scopes and profileFields

```
scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile'],
profileFields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'public-profile-url'],
```

You can see the error message [image from authentication attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hfRs.png)

I have checked my logs, i have sentry setup and logs on the server too, nothing. Authentication doesn't reach our callback url, thus no error on our side. I checked logs in developer portal, nothing. Authentication works 100% of the time for somelinkedin users, for example mine, for others it doesn't at all.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was posted here: [Single sign on failing with LinkedIn account to a microsoft website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569081/single-sign-on-failing-with-linkedin-account-to-a-microsoft-website)

I provided an answer in that post.

Comment: yes, but in your case it was failing every time. In my case it works most of the time, but sometimes failes.